# Custom User Details and Custom Authentication provider are never called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need some additional data in in the user details of authenticated users. So i wrote a custom details service and as a second approach a custom authentication provider to enrich the data in the user object. But the principal object in the security context stays a string instead of becoming the desired user object and when i'm setting breakpoints im my custom details service and authentication porvider it looks like this code is never used by spring albeit my customized classes are listed in springs authentication manager builder.

This is my custom user details service:

```
package edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb.iamservice;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/*** @author schlund*/

public class CustomStudentDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private SecurityUserRepository securityUserRepository;

    public CustomStudentDetailsService(SecurityUserRepository userSecurityRepository){
        this.securityUserRepository=userSecurityRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public SecurityUser loadUserByUsername(String kitID) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        try {
            SecurityUser securityPerson = securityUserRepository.findByUsername(kitID);
            if (securityPerson == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return securityPerson;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(SecurityUser securityPerson){
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(securityPerson.getRole());
        authorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

This is my custom authentication provider:

```
package edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb.iamservice;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication ) throws AuthenticationException {
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString().trim();
        SecurityUser appUser = new SecurityUser();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(appUser, password, null);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
      return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
  }

}
```

This is my web security config:

```
package edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.client.feign.OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;

import edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb.iamservice.*;

@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb.iamservice")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String REALM = "bam";

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider; 

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
            .logout()
            .and()
            //endpoints without authentication
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/logged", "/userData").permitAll()
            .and()
            // default with authentication
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}

    @Bean
    public OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor oAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(OAuth2ClientContext context, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(context, details);
    }

    @Bean
    BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint() {
        BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint basicAuth = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        basicAuth.setRealmName(REALM);
        return basicAuth;
    }
}
```

And at least after authentication at the code line with the System.out.println the customized services should have been called, but unfortunatelly they are not. Breakpoints in the customized services have never been reached and the principal is still a string and not my customized user:

```
@ComponentScan("edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb.iamservice")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/theses")
public class ThesisController {

    @Autowired
    private ThesisClient thesisClient;

    @Autowired
    private ThesisPersonLinker linker;

    @Autowired
    private ThesisPersonFilter filter;

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('theses')")
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<ThesisFrontendDTO>> findAllTheses() {
       System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
```

The extended user class looks like that:

```
package edu.kit.tm.cm.bamsg.bffweb.iamservice;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;


public class SecurityUser extends User{

    String firstName;
    String name;
    String password;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SecurityUser() {
        super("user", "none", null);
        firstName = "Rainer";
        name = "Schlund";
        password = "meins";
    }

    public String getRole(){
        return "Student";
    }


}
```

The code contains some simplifications for testing like SecurityPerson always returning the same person, but i think that should not be a problem.

Comment: Yes i use Spring boot, and yes WebSecurityConfig is executed, that's the place where i can check that my customized classes are listed in springs authentication manager builder.

Answer (score 2):

To address the problem of "principal object in the security context stays a string instead of becoming the desired user object" if you have gone through the Principal object it has getCreditantial() method returning object only , considering security user is principal object it is not providing enough information to become correct principal object.

Please take a look on UserDetailsPrincipal  class for principal implementation  :

```
public class UserDetailsPrincipal extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Member user;
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    
    public UserDetailsPrincipal(Member user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities ) {
        super(user.getLogin(),user.getEncrytedPassword(),authorities);
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.user = user;
    }
    
//  @Override
//  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() { 
//      return this.authorities;
//  }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getEncrytedPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return !user.getIsExpired();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !user.getIsLocked() || user.getIsLocked() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return !user.getIsExpired() || user.getIsExpired() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.getActive() == 1;
    }

}
```

2. also used customAuthProvider like this :

   @Slf4j
   @Component("customAuthProvider")
   @Transactional(readOnly = true,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

   ```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceAdapter")
    private UserDetailsServiceAdapter userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String login = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        /* Member member = userRepository.findUserAccount(login); */
        log.info("user for login inside custom auth service service  : " + login);
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(login) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            try {
                UserDetails userDetail = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsernameAndPassword(login, password);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetail,
                        userDetail.getPassword(), userDetail.getAuthorities());

                token.setDetails(userDetail);
                return token;
            } catch (UsernameNotFoundException exception) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password, new ArrayList<>());
            }
        } else {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password, new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

If you want Spring security to use your Authentication provider you need to provide some entry point for providing auth credentials. Here is example of WebSecuritConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String REALM = "realm";

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider; 

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .logout()
            .and()
            // default with authentication
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and().httpBasic().realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint());
    }

    @Bean
    BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint() {
        BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint basicAuth = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        basicAuth.setRealmName(REALM);
        return basicAuth;
    }

}
```

And you need to change SecurityUser constructor, because you cannot pass null authorities to super constructor:

```
public SecurityUser() {
        super("user", "none", new ArrayList<>());
        firstName = "Rainer";
        name = "Schlund";
        password = "meins";
}
```

When you provide Authentication provider, UserDetailsService is not used. So you need to use it in auth provider.

Comment: Added basic authentication entry point as given in example, removed null value in security user and removed custom detail service. Still principal is a string and not the desired security user.

Comment: In Authentication provider it will be username, but try using ```SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()``` in your rest controller. You will see that Principal is an SecurityUser object.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not it is still a String with ufeug as value. That's my user login.

Comment: I updated the websecurityconfig at the top of the page, in App main i have:
    "@SpringBootApplication
    @EnableZuulProxy
    @EnableFeignClients(defaultConfiguration = BamsgBffWebApplication.FeignConfiguration.class)"

Comment: @hya, i think the reason your solution didn't fix his issue is because he is utilizing the EnableOath2Sso annotation. (i know this is old, just something i noticed as i was looking for other answers)